# Generated json not including certain fields of POJO class

Tags: jersey

I have a complex Employee POJO class which has Name, id, salary, dept and Address(vector type) fields.I have generated the json using the jersey restful web service. But the output json does not include the certain pojo fields like address which has datatype as vector. All the fields in POJO class has getter and setters.

Any specific reason that why certain fields are not part of generated JSON ?

//Used below code to generate the JSON

```
     @Path("/employeedDetails")
             @GET
             @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})         
             public EmployeedBean getDetails(@QueryParam("Id") String Id, 
                   @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
 Employee e1 = new Employee();
```

// Sets all  Name, id, salary, dept and Address
    return e1;
}

Comment: Could you add your POJO class?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing code. Can you post what you are returning? If you are returning an array (such as a Java List object), you'll want to wrap that inside another POJO class. I was having the same issue (see [RESTful POJO -> JSON mapping not picking up new fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957176/restful-pojo-json-mapping-not-picking-up-new-fields/17983662#17983662)) and this was what was causing it, since the returned JSON was starting with brackets [] instead of {} and therefore JavaScript wasn't parsing it properly. Returning a single object instead of a List fixed the issue.